# facing with "list index out of range" error when using objects

Tags: python

I want to make list of objects. My code is:

```
std_list_instance = list()
for i in range(0, std_cls_1_num):  #std_cls_1_num set by user
    std = Student(std_cls_1_list[0][i], std_cls_1_list[1][i], std_cls_1_list[2][i])  #Student has 3 fields that given from a list 
    std_list_instance[i].append(std)
```

class def is:

```
class Student:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, age, height, weight):
        self.age = age
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        Student.count += 1
    def get_ave_age(self):
        print('age is %i' %self.age)
```

std_cls_1_list is:

```
std_cls_1_list = list()
for i in range(0, 3):
    std_cls_1_list.append([int(std_cls_1_num) for std_cls_1_num in input().split()])
```

and finally user input is like:

```
5 #number of student
16 17 15 16 17  #age of 5 std
180 175 172 170 165 #height of 5 std
67 72 59 62 55 #weight of 5 std
```

then I faced with "list index out of range error".
I know there is a problem in my code, but I can't fix it.

Comment: Please add the definition of `Student`, and how does `std_cls_1_list` looks like

Comment: You want `std_list_instance.append(std)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to switch accessing list elements. Instead of `[0][i]` do `[i][0]`:

```
std_list_instance = list()
for i in range(0, std_cls_1_num):  #std_cls_1_num set by user
    std = Student(std_cls_1_list[i][0], std_cls_1_list[i][1], std_cls_1_list[i][2])  #Student has 3 fields that given from a list 
    std_list_instance[i].append(std)
```

But you will still get the error if:

1. `std_cls_1_num > len(std_cls_1_list)` - `std_cls_1_num` greater than number of elements in `std_cls_1_list`
2. `not all(len(st) > 3 for st in std_cls_1_list)` - not every element of `std_cls_1_list` has at least 3 elements

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure the size of “std_cls_1_num” must be equal or less then the size of “std_cls_1_list” rows..if its greater then the row size the program will throw index error.

Also if possible please put the related code/definitions/input then only we can comment..